# Better strategy to update a CursorAdapter's databse when its Cursor from web differs from him

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio

I'm building an webcrawler that gets data from the web, stores into a database, then uses a CursorLoader to get these data from the database and put in the CursorAdapter. Then, I have an Async Task responsible to get data from the web periodically, but instead of rewriting the entire database, I'd like to only update the new items, but there's a problem: In order to update only the newer items, I need load these items. Of course I don't want to load them 2 times, so I need to use my CursorLoader, and only update the items in the database if the CursorLoader already loaded. I want to know what's the best technique for making sure it already loaded.

I could put a Boolean data on the onLoadFinished of my LoaderManager that updates to true when the loader has already loaded.

I could inspect the adapter, get its cursor and see if it's null or not

I could... What would you do? I want to make it elegant, I want to learn better programming pratices!

Comment: Try a Sync Adapter --> http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to write this I would use `ContentProvider` along with `CursorLoader` to accomplish this. One of the benefits of this method is that you can have your URI to be loaded in `CursorLoader` and if the data in the underlying database has been changed, `ContentProvider` will notify that the URI data has been changed and data will be loaded automatically.

`ContentProvider` may seem to have a little extra work at first but at the end it worth it. So basically you need the following steps:

1- Design a `DBContract` and `SQLiteOpenHelper`

2- Design URIs you are going to use and create a `ContentProvider` with a URIMatcher

3- Design a `SyncAdapter` or `AsyncTask` to load data into the DB through `ContentProvider`

4- Use `CursorLoader` to load data on your fragment/activity

Whenever you fetch new data, your fragment/activity data will be updated automatically